# Navbar buttons only pull right on smaller screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to setup a navbar so that there is a brand icon (currently just using placeholder text) on the left, and two buttons on the right of the navbar. [Here is the JSFiddle showing this](http://jsfiddle.net/t647o8nx/).

The problem I am running into is that this works as expected on smaller screens, but when my browser is full size everything seems to pull left. Is there a class that I am missing?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Business Name</a>
      <form class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signInModal">
          Sign In
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal">
          Sign Up
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the divs that Bootstrap expects to be there are missing as well as the mobile hamburger menu. Try something more like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/njkcaqvu/